# Naming routes different from Controller / Database

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In a Laravel 5.8 app i want my url's to be in Dutch, however, for consistency and just general easier use, i want to name everything else by their English names. Eloquent will ( as far as i know ) only pass me the proper vars if my Model, Controller, table etc. are all named the same.

Right now, i have a route named /backend/facturen which in English would be /backend/invoices. I have tried using names routes, however, i found that this wasn't what i was looking for.

My route:

```php
Route::resource('/backend/facturen', 'InvoicesController');
```

My show method inside the InvoicesController:

```
public function show(Invoice $invoice) {
    return view('backend.invoice.show', compact('invoice'));
}
```

The database table is named 'invoices'.

The only way so far i have got this to work is by renaming my route to:

```
Route::resource('/backend/invoices', 'InvoicesController');
```

But, of course, this is not a solution to my problem.

I would like to see all data from the invoices show up on my ( Dutch ) /facturen route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource controllers by default look for a variable with the same name as the (last part of the) URL, so renaming the URL changes that variable as well.

But you can [tell Laravel to use a different name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters):

```php
Route::resource('/backend/facturen', 'InvoicesController')->parameters([
    'facturen' => 'invoice'
]);
```

Comment: This was what i was looking for. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You could also get the variable itself from the id, without using the laravel magic to correctly detecting the variable from the url:

```
public function show($id) {
    $invoice = Invoice::findOrFail($id);

    return view('backend.invoice.show', compact('invoice'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have registered a route pointing to the URL `/backend/facturen`, to name it, use the [`name`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) function:

```
Route::resource('/backend/facturen', 'InvoicesController')->name('backend.invoice.show');
```

Even then, it won't show that route, when using the [`view`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views) function you need to pass the path to your template, not the route.

Comment: I might be wrong, but won't this work since it's a resource controller?